# How can I use the ./gradlew deployNodes with the enterprise version of corda jar

Tags: corda

How can I use the ./gradlew deployNodes with the enterprise version of corda.jar?

I could not see how to specify this in the Cordform: https://docs.corda.net/generating-a-node.html

Answer (score 0):

DeployNodes is a task that starts the bootstrapped mock network which uses the open sources version of Corda.

If you are currently evaluating Corda Enterprise, please contact sales@r3.com for the guideline of testing Corda enterprise.

Answer (score 0):

1. Make the CE dependencies available to your build. The corda-4.x-developer-pack includes a *repository* folder you can deploy to your private Maven repo or just use directly like

```
repositories {
    //...
    maven {
        url "file://$rootDir/path_to_devpack/repository"
    }
}
```

2. Switch to the appropriate `corda_release_group` and `corda_release_version` in your `ext` section of your *build.gradle*:

```
ext {
    //...
    corda_release_group = 'com.r3.corda' // VS 'net.corda'
    corda_release_version =  '4.3' // or whatever
}
```

3. If needed, substitute transitive Corda OS dependencies with their CE equivalents:

```
allprojects {
    //...
    configurations {
        all {
            //...
            resolutionStrategy {
                // ...
                eachDependency { DependencyResolveDetails details ->
                    // Exclude from substitutions as appropriate
                    def exclusions = ['corda-finance-contracts']
                    // Substitute the rest, assumes `ext.corda_release_group` and `ext.corda_release_version` are set
                    if (details.requested.group ==  "net.corda" && !exclusions.contains(details.requested.name)) {
                        // Force Corda Enterprise
                        details.useTarget  group:  corda_release_group, name: details.requested.name, version: corda_release_version
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```